# C/C++ Constants

Tags: c++, c, constants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [const int = int const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247285/const-int-int-const)

What is the difference between these combination of keywords ?

```
const int*

int const*

int* const
```

Is it possible to modify the value of a constant by accessing its address using a pointer ?

Comment: Thinking in C++ by Bruce Eckel is an excellent book that explains most all the corners of C++ including a section about the differences of syntax similar to this when using const and *

Comment: const binds to the left unless it is on the very left then in binds right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general:

```
   const T            ===               T const
```

and

```
   const T *          ===               T const *
```

*but*

```
   T * const
```

makes the *pointer* constant, but not necessarily the *contents of T*.

```
    const T * const      ===         T const * const
```

will make both the contents of T and the pointer itself constants.

As for changing the contents of a `const`: you *shouldn't be able to*, but the compiler/OS/CPU don't try too hard to stop you, so you get what is colloquially called “undefined behaviour,” which is a nice way of saying “random crashes on some systems”

Answer (score 3):

```
const int*

int const*
```

Both declare an pointer to an constant type `int`. It means that the pointer can be made to point to(hold) any other address but any attempt to modify the constant integer data type will result in **Undefined Behavior**.

```
int* const
```

Declares an constant pointer to an `int` type. It means that the pointer cannot be assigned any new address it will always keep pointing to the same address, but the integer it points to can be changed.

**Is it possible to modify the value of a constant by accessing its address using a pointer ?**

Yes, it is possible but it leads to a ill formed program exhibiting an **Undefined Behavior**.

Comment: Correction - the int is not necessarily a constant. Attempts to modify the int through the pointer will result in an error at *compile-time.*

Answer (score 1):

The first two are a variable pointer to a const int. The pointer itself can be changed. Without casting away const, the int can't be changed through this pointer. (It may, however, be modifiable through non-const references.)

The last is a const pointer to a variable int. Without casting away const, the pointer itself can't be changed. The int can be changed through the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

`const int*` and `int const*` are both a pointer to a constant int. This means that the value pointed to can not be changed but the pointer itself can be.

The third example `int *const` is a constant pointer to an int. This means that the value can be changed but the pointer can not.

Yes you can change the value of the address by using a pointer but doing so is undefined behavior and should be avoided. `C++` also offers a [`const_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) to remove the `const`ness of a variable.

If you have any other questions related to the `const` keyword you should reference the [const correctness section of the C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html).

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://duramecho.com/ComputerInformation/WhyHowCppConst.html) may be helpful. [This](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c/browse_thread/thread/860be00649b49b4a/e44e3d249f1cd41f?lnk=st&rnum=1&hl=en&pli=1) is another one that talks about breaking it apart so you can see which parts become `const` in various scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Const binds to the left.
Unless it is the left most clause then in binds right.

Just read right to left

```
const int*  => (const int)*  => "pointer" to "const int" 
                             => Pointer can change.
                             => Can't change the value it points at (the int is const)

int const*  => (int const)*  => "pointer" to "const int"
                             => As above

int* const  => int (* const) => "const pointer" to "int"
                             => Can't change the pointer (its const) it always points
                             => at the same things.
                             => You can change the value of the object it points at.
```