# Returning vector of pointers?

Tags: c++, syntax, constants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between const int*, const int * const, and int const *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262)
>   [const int = int const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247285/const-int-int-const)

What's the difference between the following three?

```
vector<int const *> f() { ... }

vector<const int *> g() { ... }

vector<int * const> h() { ... }
```

Comment: this might help you with constant pointers and pointers to constants http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/general/article.php/c6967

Comment: Probably not an exact duplicate. The answer, btw, is that the first two are the same, and the third is an error, as `int * const` does not comply with the requirements that `std::vector` places on the contained type (in particular assignability)

Answer (score 3):

Nothing (except the name of the function).

In both cases, `const` modifies the `int`, not the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference; `int const` and `const int` mean the same thing.

Ordinarily, `const` refers to the type on its *left*:  a `int const *` is a pointer to a constant integer, not a constant pointer to a (non-constant) integer.  Putting `const` at the very beginning is a special case, where it refers to the type on its *right*.

Answer (score 0):

One's named f, the other is named g.  That's it.

const is applied to the element to the left.  In the case where there is no element to the left, it is applied to the element to the right.