# why is the value printed is 25 ? shouldn't that be a memory location value ?

Tags: c

I was working with c puzzles, and came across this question . 
In here , a at printf statement the pointer gets incremented once, so i thought it will be pointing to the random number !
but I cant understand why 25 is the output?
could anyone please help me understand ?
Many thanks in advance;)

```
void main()

{

      int  const * p=5;

      printf("%d",++(*p));

}
```

Answer: 25

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You **are** pointing at a random piece of memory (address 5).  You're then incrementing whatever happens to be stored there, and printing the result.  This is **undefined behaviour**; your program could do anything.

**UPDATE:** Actually, this code shouldn't even compile.  You've declared it as a pointer to `const`, so the compiler shouldn't let you increment.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: I think it`s a const pointer, so incrementing value at the target should be ok.

Comment: it's `int const *`, not `const int *`: `++p` would be illegal, not `++*p`

Comment: @CAFxX: `int const *` and `const int *` are the same thing.

Comment: @drhirsch: That would be `int *const p`.

Comment: `int const * == const int *`... what you mean is `int * const`, `const` can go on any side but to avoid confusion it should always be put right of the type and constness read from right to left.

Comment: @Bort: To avoid confusion?  I think the above comments prove otherwise. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694630/c-const-reference-before-vs-after-type-specifier/3695979#3695979

Comment: @jamesdlin well, my opinion: that's why left `const type` should always be warned by the compiler! I know a lot of people write code otherwise but that's the source of the confusion if `const` is used in advanced types like here (and precedence rules apply). I learned it the hard way exactly because of this (imho) bad style.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is wrong. Its making a pointer from an integer without a cast.Also your declaration makes `p` a pointer to an constant integer and you cannot increment the value pointed to by pointer `p`. Also its the value and not the pointer that will get incremented in the `printf` statement.

Comment: Type cast is not really required in C

Comment: I agree to that but then again its certainly not "correct" to go about assigning integers to pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we are assigning a constant to a pointer, it should be like `int  const * p=(unsigned int*)5`. If you are lucky, 5 would be in your program's address space. If not, then you get a seg fault. That's why it's undefined behavior. Check this for more details on int const, const int etc. [const int = int const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247285/const-int-int-const)

Comment: Or, even more clear details are here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-int-const

Comment: I would argue that you are **un**-lucky if 5 is currently mapped in your address space.