# I am unable to determine why this C program gives me this answer

Tags: c, pointers, constants

Unable to know why output is 6?
In the given C program I am getting output as 6 every time, so I can't say that it is      printing Garbage value

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int const* a=2; 
    printf("%d\n",++(a));
}
```

I am unable to determine why this C program gives me this answer.

Comment: Because `2 + sizeof(int)` is 6 on your computer.

Comment: Cause you're printing a pointer value without dereferencing it.

Comment: Don't use `%d` to print pointers address, this may lead to problems on some systems. Use `%p` instead.

Comment: ... and then when printing a pointer with `"%p"`, as you ought to, cast the value passed to `void *`, as `"%p"` is only defined for pointers to `void`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/394767/694576

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually quite easy to debug to see what is going on here. Run this piece of code and look at the values:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int const* a=2;

    printf("Size of int %d\n", sizeof(int));
    printf("Size of int const* %d\n", sizeof(int const*));
    printf("Size of a %d\n", sizeof(a));
    printf("Not incremented %d\n", a);
    printf("Incremented %d\n",++(a));

    return 0;
}
```

I get the output:

```
Size of int 4
Size of int const* 8
Size of a 8
Not incremented 2
Incremented 6
```

On a 64-bit machine. Clearly this demonstrates that when you do '++(a)' you are adding 2 to the size of an int. Why should this be the case when you declared

```
int const* a=2;
```

?

Well, that is because you are adding 2 to the size of the ***pointer type*** rather than the size of the pointer. Change to:

```
long const* a = 2;
```

To observe the differences and see this is the case.

This is a quirk of the C/C++ language.

Answer (score 9):

When you increment a pointer, it actually increments by the size of the type that it is pointing to.

Here you initialise a pointer to the value `2`. You then increment the pointer which, by the above increments the pointer by `sizeof(int)` or `4` on your system. You then print out this value - 6.

Comment: It adjusted your wording. However +1 for a straight forward not too theoretical answer.

Answer (score 2):

You create `int` pointer and set it to point to address `2`. When you try to print, you actually do pointer math (not incrementing value of pointed `int`). Size of `int` is 4 bytes, thus, 2 + 4 = 6.

If you want to access value of pointed `int`, then need to use `*`:

```
int *a = malloc(sizeof(int));
*a = 2;
printf("%d\n", ++(*a));
```

Note, you can't declare `a` as `const`, because this code will change value of it.
If you want to make a constant pointer (so, you can't change an address it pointer, but still can change data), you need to place `const` after `*`:

```
int * const a = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Comment: `int const *a` is OK though (that means the things being pointed to are const, not `a`)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Actually `int const *a` (or `const int *a`) would declare a pointer whose data cannot be changed. To make constant pointer (but changeable data), it must be declared `int * const a`.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247285/const-int-int-const

Comment: @MattMcNabb Ok, just misunderstanding and language barrier. :)
Anyway, I have added more detailed explanation `const` to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is invalid in more than one way.

Firstly, it is illegal to initialize a pointer with a numerical value (other than constant zero). This

```
int const* a = 2;
```

is not valid C.

Secondly, it is not legal to use `%d` format specifier to print pointer values. `%d` is for integers, not for pointers. Which means that this

```
printf("%d\n",++(a));
```

produces undefined behavior.

Thirdly, `main` must return `int`, not `void`.

Finally, if your compiler actually swallowed this code and spewed out some sort of executable in return, then one would expect it to print `6`. You pointer initialization will "typically" make it point to address `2`. Your increment will "typically" increase that address by size of `int`. Size of `int` is "typically" `4`. `2 + 4` equals `6`. `%d` format specifier applied to pointer will "typically" print decimal representation of the address the pointer is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `int const* a = 2;` is wrong. You could use `int const* a = (int const*)2;` instead. But there is a question about your aim.

Really Do you want to print the pointer value or the value that `a` points to?

Be careful that `a` points to a constant value which is not modifiable.