# What is the difference between const string & str and string const & str when passed as an argument to a function in c++

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, constants, string-constant

I am using pass by reference to const string in a function argument like below:

```
class Super
{
   void alignment(const string & str);
};

void Super::alignment(const string & str)
{
  //do some stuff
}
```

Now if I use as below it gives the same result:

```
void Super::alignment(string const & str)
{
  //do some stuff
}
```

What is the difference in this two types of definition in c++?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Const Usage Explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598703/c-const-usage-explanation)

Comment: none, the `const` qualifier can be before or after the type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [const int = int const?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247285/const-int-int-const)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`const T&` and `T const&` are semantically the same exact thing. Just like `const T*` and `T const*` are semantically the same, but `T const*` and `T* const` [are different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const?rq=1).

Answer (score 4):

the const keyword is left associative, but in "const string &str", since there's no left keyword to qualify, it apply to the word at his right (so string).

It is the same but it's not parsed the same.