# Why is this Pointer to Constant Pointer assignment Illegal?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

```
int x = 10;
int * const p = &x;
const int **p1 = &p;
```

Having some trouble understanding why this is illegal.

EDIT

Thank you for all the great answers.
Here is my interpretation of the answers, feel free to disagree.
So, the error is in the 3rd line. It implies that original integer is constant but does not imply that the pointer it points to is constant and therefore it is illegal because we could attempt to change the pointer 'p' through  'p1' which is not possible because that is a constant pointer. So to fix this the third line must be:

```
int * const *p1 = &p;
```

This works because it says that while the original integer is non-constant (mutable) the pointer it points to is constant and therefore it is a legal statement. So this is also legal:

```
const int * const *p1 = &p;
```

This says the same thing except it also says that you cant change the original integer because it is constant.

Comment: What's your intent with `int * const p`?

Comment: when there is a error message you should include it in the question, usually they already give a hint on what is wrong

Comment: @tadman It is actually the opposite - `int * const p` creates a const pointer to mutable value, and then he tries to get a mutable pointer to mutable pointer to const value.

Comment: @VTT You've explained it correctly. That notation is really unusual, which is why I got confused.

Comment: @tadman You may want to check [Straight declarations library](https://github.com/guaranteed-to-be-unique/Straight-Declarations) - it makes it possible to declare pointers without using spiral reading rules.

Comment: @vtt A neat tool, but in this case probably just needed to pay closer attention to the declaration.

Comment: this might help: https://cdecl.org/

Comment: In a nutshell, it is illegal because it is a 1 way street: non-const to const is fine but const to non-const isn't

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something you need to get used to with pointer declarations is that you need to try reading them right to left.  What matters is what's on each side of the `*`

`int * const p` means `p` is a **const pointer** to a **non-const int**

`const int **p1` means `p1` is a **non-const pointer** to a **non-const pointer** to a **const int**

Your second declaration fails because it creates a non-const variable from a const one.

Comment: almost correct, according to your last sentence this shouldnt work: `const int x = 3; int y = x;`

Comment: I understand what you're saying but even this does not work and seems to follow that logic:`const int ci = 42;
 const int * const p3 = &ci;
 const int ** p = &p3;`

Comment: At the top level, it's a copy, so the const doesn't matter.  Const that is "wrapped inside" a pointer or reference sticks.  Taking the address of something const cannot be assigned to something that holds the address of something non-const, or you could end up changing the const value through just by looking at it through the non-const lens (without a cast.)

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis yes, thank you for clarifying where I failed to elaborate

Answer (score 2):

Initializes new mutable `int` `x` with literal `10`, fine:

```
int x = 10;
```

Initializes new constant pointer to mutable `int` `p` with address of `x`, fine:

```
int * const p = &x;
```

Initializes new mutable pointer to mutable pointer to constant `int` with address of `p`, constraint violation due to stripping the `const`, and also due to adding the inner-most `const`:

```
const int **p1 = &p;
// Normally qualifiers go to the right of the type they qualify
// The inner-most qualifiers can be put before them though without introducing ambiguity
```

[Read the full rules on cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Qualification_conversions) or directly in the standard, they are a bit long.

Comment: "and also due to adding the inner-most const" adding const should not be a problem, removing is

Comment: @Slava It can be, and in this case it is a problem. See the link for the nitty-gritty.

Answer (score 1):

Declares 2 ints which are constant:

```
int const x1 = 3;
const int x2 = 3;
```

Declares a pointer whose data cannot be changed through the pointer:

```
const int *p = &someInt;
```

Declares a pointer who cannot be changed to point to something else:

```
int * const p = &someInt;
```

Link: [const int = int const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247285/const-int-int-const)

Answer (score 0):

The compiler (here, gcc) tells you

```
invalid conversion from 'int* const*' to 'const int**' [-fpermissive]
```

And the reason is that

p1 is a pointer to (non-`const`) pointer to `const` int

while

p is a `const` pointer to int

If the assignment was legal, you could modify the `const` variable `p` through `p1` (as the type of *p1 would be `const int *` -- pointer to const int).

Answer (score 0):

In

`int * const p = &x;`

that means the address/reference is constant, since the `const` comes after `*` (as opposed to the target value being constant, in other words `const` before the `*`, in other words `const int *p`)

In

`const int **p1 = &p;`

that means, `p1`, which I'll call the "outer pointer" points to `const int *`, which is wrong, b.c. it should be pointing to an `int *const` as the previous expression states.

In other words, as the compiler puts it,

```
error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'const int **' with an rvalue of type 'int *const *'
const int **p1 = &p;
```