# Difference between Const int & int const?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

is there a difference between
Const int dd{4}; &
Int const dd{4};.

The dd is non modifiable in both cases, so what is the difference?

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247285/const-int-int-const/5347716

Comment: Yes sir, thank you.