# Vala - constant instead of magic number

Tags: c, gtk, constants, vala

In C I can do something like

```
#define SIZE 16
int c[SIZE];
```

but in Vala when I do

```
const int SIZE = 16;
int c[SIZE];
```

I get error during compiling that ends with "undeclared here (not in a function)"

Is there any way to remove magic numbers in vala and replace them with constants?

Comment: Do you think `#define SIZE 16` and `const int SIZE = 16;` are same?

Comment: of course not, but it's the closest thing I could think of

Comment: Where you placed `int c[SIZE];`? Inside `main`/function or you declared it as global?

Comment: I placed constant and array in same class that I create(call) in main

Comment: I am not able to figure out the actual problem. It would be helpful to us if you will post some more code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why the size of array as a constant variable is not allowed in C but allowed in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25902512/why-the-size-of-array-as-a-constant-variable-is-not-allowed-in-c-but-allowed-in)

Comment: [“static const” vs “#define” in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1674032/995714), [Can a const variable be used to declare the size of an array in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18848537/995714)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc The answers you linked explain the difference between a constant and a preprocessor define, but Vala doesn't have a preprocessor (only conditional compilation). So this question is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic allocation is the way to go:

```
const int SIZE = 16;
int[] c = new int[SIZE];
```

Especially if SIZE is part of some C header file that you are binding to via a vapi file.

In the vapi case static allocation works as well:

mylib.h

```
#define MYLIB_SIZE 16
```

mylib.vapi

```
namespace Mylib {

    // You can optionally specify the cname here:
    //[CCode (cname = "MYLIB_SIZE")]
    const int SIZE;
}
```

main.vala

```
int c[Mylib.SIZE];
```

Comment: that is awesome :) thank you, as soon as I get home I'll try that....looks promising though :)