# Why does a const int not get optimized by the compiler (through the symbol table) if another pointer points to its reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants, compiler-optimization

This is a follow up on an answer in this question: [What kind of optimization does const offer in C/C++? (if any)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27466642/what-kind-of-optimization-does-const-offer-in-c-c-if-any)

In the top voted answer, the following is stated:

When you declare a const in your program,

```
int const x = 2;
```

Compiler can optimize away this const by not providing storage to this variable rather add it in symbol table. So, subsequent read just need indirection into the symbol table rather than instructions to fetch value from memory.

NOTE:- If you do something like below:-

```
const int x = 1;
const int* y = &x;
```

Then **this would force compiler to allocate space for 'x'**. So, that degree of optimization is not possible for this case.

**Why is this the case? Looks like you will never be able to change x anyway, no?**

Comment: The "compiler" seems to be an important part in this.

Comment: But how do you use `y`? Otherwise the compiler could optimize away both? And depending on *how* you use `y` then it might be able to do it anyway.

Comment: Edited the title to include compiler

Comment: If a pointer is initialised to contain the address of a variable, and that pointer can be accessed from another compilation unit, then it would be reasonable for the compiler to allow for the possibility that the pointer IS dereferenced after being initialised in some compilation unit that is not visible to the compiler.  One consequence of that is not optimising the pointer or the variable out of existence.    There are numerous other reasoning approaches that might lead to the same outcome, depending on what code the compiler can actually see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, Peter provided the explanation in his comment:

> If a pointer is initialised to contain the address of a variable, and that pointer can be accessed from another compilation unit, then it would be reasonable for the compiler to allow for the possibility that the pointer IS dereferenced after being initialised in some compilation unit that is not visible to the compiler. One consequence of that is not optimising the pointer or the variable out of existence. There are numerous other reasoning approaches that might lead to the same outcome, depending on what code the compiler can actually see.

and this is exactly what I think too.

The `const` in C++ is a little bit confusing. It looks like the abbreviation of “constant” but actually it means “read-only”.

This in mind, I never wondered why the following code is legal in C:

```
enum { N = 3 };
static int a[N]; /* legal in C: N is a constant. */
```

but this not:

```
const int n = 3;
static int b[n]; /* illegal in C: n is a read-only variable */
```

When I switched to C++, I assumed the above for C++ until I realized in a discussion with a colleague that I was wrong. (Not that this broke any written code of mine, but I hate it to be wrong.) ;-)

```
const int n = 3;
static int b[n]; // legal in C++
```

and [Const propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) is the technique which makes it legal.

However, even with const propagation `const int x;` is still a read-only variable which might be addressed.

The OP provided a link about this topic (which might explain it even better than above):

[SO: why the size of array as a constant variable is not allowed in C but allowed in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25902625/7478597)

To make this a ful-featured answer I tried to prepare a sample which illustrates the differences:

```
#include <iostream>

const int x1 = 1;
static const int x1s = 11;
extern const int x1e = 12;

const int x2 = 2;
extern const int *const pX2 = &x2;

const int x3 = 3;
static const int *const pX3 = &x3;

int main()
{
  // make usage of values (to have a side-effect)
  std::cout << x1;
  std::cout << x1s;
  std::cout << x1e;
  std::cout << x2;
  std::cout << pX2;
  std::cout << x3;
  std::cout << pX3;
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

and the outcome of `gcc 8.2` with `-O3`:

```
; int main()
main:
; {
 sub rsp, 8
;   // make usage of values (to have a side-effect)
;   std::cout << x1;
  mov esi, 1
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
  call _ZNSolsEi
;   std::cout << x1s;
  mov esi, 11
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
  call _ZNSolsEi
;   std::cout << x1e;
  mov esi, 12
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
  call _ZNSolsEi
;   std::cout << x2;
  mov esi, 2
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
  call _ZNSolsEi
;   std::cout << pX2;
  mov esi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZL2x2
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
  call _ZNSo9_M_insertIPKvEERSoT_
;   std::cout << x3;
  mov esi, 3
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
  call _ZNSolsEi
;   std::cout << pX3;
  mov esi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZL2x3
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
  call _ZNSo9_M_insertIPKvEERSoT_
;   // done
;   return 0;
; }
  xor eax, eax
  add rsp, 8
  ret
```

and the IMHO most interesting part – the global variables:

```
; const int x3 = 3;
_ZL2x3:
  .long 3
; extern const int *const pX2 = &x2;
pX2:
  .quad _ZL2x2
; const int x2 = 2;
_ZL2x2:
  .long 2
; extern const int x1e = 12;
x1e:
  .long 12
```

1. `x1`, `x1s`, and `pX3` have been optimized away because they are `const` and not remarked for external linkage.
2. `x1e` and `pX2` have been allocated because they are remarked for external linkage.
3. `x2` has been allocated because it is referred by `pX2` which is remarked for external linkage. (Something from extern may access `x2` via `pX2`.)
4. `x3` was the most tricky one for me. `pX3` has been used (in `std::cout << pX3;`). Although, its value itself is inlined it refers to `x3`. Furthermore, although the access to `x3` (in `std::cout << x3;`) was inlined as well, the usage of the pointer `pX3` initialized with `&x3` prevented to optimize this storage away.

[**Live Demo on godbolt**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/E-XxOI) (which has a nice colored dual-view to make it easy to explore)

I did the same with `clang 7.0.0` and the outcome was similar.

(I tried it also with `msvc v19.15` but I was not able (not patient enough) to evaluate the outcome.)

---

Concerning 4., I tried additionally:

```
const int x4 = 4;
static const int *const pX4 = &x4;
```

and added to `main()`:

```
  std::cout << x4;
  // No: std::cout << pX4;
```

In this case, there was no storage allocated – neither for `x4` nor for `pX4`. (`pX4` was optimized away, leaving no “reference” to `x4` which in turn was optimized away as well.)

It's amazing...

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.  Definitely needed a quick refresher on assembly and registers, once I got that, everything made sense.  The example illustrates Peter's answer very clearly imo.

With regards to your slight detour though, is const propagation really the reason why C++ allows const as array size but not C?  I thought it was because you could use `x` from `const int x` directly as a const since C++ regards it as so, while C does not.  See the following for better explanations than mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25902512/

Comment: @kop_padawan The link you provided does explain this very precisely, I agree. My imagination of "constant" was coined when I was a student and learned Pascal. In Pascal, a constant is nothing addressable and clearly distinguished from a variable. However, this is about C++ and C, so it might be questionable to apply that principles (though I assumed until now that that principle is language agnostic, at least, for imperative languages, but this might be wrong). And, btw. it's decades ago that I was a student... ;-)

Comment: @kop_padawan About your concerns regarding "Const propagation" - I'm not quite sure. From the linked Wikipedia article: _Constant propagation is the process of substituting the values of known constants in expressions at compile time._ I guessed it covers also: The semantic analysis can replace the const variable (e.g. in an array size) by its compile-time computed value to enable proper allocation. May be, I got it wrong and "Const prop." is rather the term exclusively used for optimization phase. I would've enjoyed to discuss (and fix) this but instead I got a downvote without any remark...

Comment: The downvote didnt come from me :) I did upvote and accept the answer though.  Also not a student despite the username, heh.

Comment: @kop_padawan I didn't think so. Anonymous downvoters don't articulate doubts or critics in comments. ;-) Luckily, there seem to be not so many that it's worth to worry about this...