# Getting the address of a pointer assigns it a value

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm testing pointers with C++ and I just noticed that when I do something like this:

```
int main(){
int* test;
std::cout << test << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

it would output 0 and when I do something like this:

```
int main(){
int* test;
&test;
std::cout << test << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

it outputs a valid memory address.
Does anyone have an idea on why this happens?

Comment: Its uninitialized. It could print anything.

Comment: I guessed so, but the assembly code also changes when I get it's reference

Comment: Like tkausl said, it is uninitialised, but a compiler can make it zero if it so wishes to. Your `&test;` line doesn't do anything and should not show up in the final assembly. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: You're code has undefined behavior.  Any result is correct.

Comment: When you print the address of something, it may happen that something actually gets an address due to this. In your first example, `test` does not necessarily need to exist in memory - a register would be sufficient as well. In the 2nd case, you explicitly ask for the address - so, it has to get one.

Comment: FYI: [SO: Why does a const int not get optimized by the compiler (through the symbol table) if another pointer points to its reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53349946/7478597)

Comment: Yeah in the first assembly the pointer doesn't get pushed to the stack, I guess it was using a register as it's value, in the second it pushes some value onto it, I'm using g++ btw

Comment: @Cufox You are a magician!

Comment: I guess it getting a value makes more sense, what's confusing me now is why that value is a valid memory address and not a garbage value

Comment: Define "valid". How do you distinguish between "a valid memory address" and "a garbage value", when neither actually points to an `int` that exists?

Comment: as in it looks normal and I can work with it, do pointers get special garbage values?

Comment: Define "looks normal". In what sense can you "work with it"?

Comment: I can dereference it, perform memmove on it, it works like a normal pointer, except I have no idea where it points and so far no seg faults were thrown

Comment: That you "can" do those things is an illusion. Do not "expect" segmentation faults from the use of invalid pointers. That is only one possible result. The operating system doesn't detect _all_ bad accesses (unless you use some debug tool to make it do so), usually only those that cross page boundaries or such.

Comment: I see! thank you this makes much more sense now :>

Comment: No probs. I've added that to my answer as it seems to be a critical part of your question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr: Compilers are complex, and undefined behaviour allows them to do all sorts of things.**

---

> ```
> int* test;
> std::cout << test << std::endl;
> ```

Using `test` (even just to evaluate its own value!) in this manner when it hasn't been given a value is not permitted, so your program has undefined behaviour.

Your compiler apparently uses this fact to take some particular path. Perhaps it's assuming a zero value, or it's prepared to optimise away the variable and leave you only with some hardcoded thing. It's arbitrarily picked zero for that thing, because why not? The value is unspecified by the standard, so that's fine.

> ```
> &test;
> ```

This is another thing. It is perfectly legal to take the address of an uninitialised thing, so *this aspect* of your program is well-defined. It appears that this triggers a path in the compiler that prepares to create actual, honest-to-god storage for the pointer. This odr-use effectively prevents any of the optimise-it-out machinery. Somehow, that's taken it down a road that doesn't trigger the "pretend it's zero" case, and you end up with (possibly) some actual, memory read instead; that memory read results in the unspecified value that you have come to expect from outputting uninitialised things.

That value is still "garbage", though. You indicate that you "can" deference it, that you "can" memmove it, that you "can" work with it without triggering a segmentation fault. But this is all an illusion! Do not "expect" segmentation faults from the use of invalid pointers. That is only one possible result. The operating system doesn't detect all bad accesses (unless you use some debug tool to make it do so), usually only those that cross page boundaries or such.

Anyway, the specifics of the above are complete speculation but it shows the sort of factors that can go into different outcomes of programs with undefined behaviour. Ultimately there is not a lot of point in trying to rationalise about this sort of code, and there is certainly no point in writing it!

Comment: Yup I think this explains it fully,  guess I should stop questioning undefined behaviour!

Comment: @Cufox You'll only make yourself mad ;) That being said, there are benefits to having some familiarity with common outcomes; if you're hunting some bug, that experience will make spotting UB a little easier. The number of times I've muttered "this smells like UB..." and refocused my attention on buffer overruns etc and thus found the fault, is not insubstantial.

Comment: yeah it's kinda why I was testing this, I thought I saw some source code of someone actually using a pointer like that and I wanted to test it out! thx again! :)

Comment: @Cufox Cool. Don't forget to file a bug report to that person ;)