# constexpr vs const vs constexpr const

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr

[const-vs-constexpr-on-variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13347355/6053907)

What the guy says about constexpr is right `if double` is used (or `float` of course). However, if you change the var type from `double` to an integer type like int, char, etc, everything works. Why does that happen?

http://ideone.com/DAWABE

```
int main() 
{
    const int PI1 = 3;
    constexpr int PI2 = 3;
    constexpr int PI3 = PI1;  // works
    static_assert(PI1 == 3, "");  // works

    const double PI1__ = 3.0;
    constexpr double PI2__ = 3.0;
    constexpr double PI3__ = PI1__;  // error
    static_assert(PI1__ == 3.0, "");  // error
    return 0;
}
```

`Update`: the following line was a mistake, I meant `PI3__ = PI1__`

```
constexpr double PI3__ = PI1;  // I meant PI1__
```

Questions:

1. Why `const int = 3` is  compile time constant but `const double = 3.0` is not?
2. Is there any reason why I should use `constexpr const int val;` over `constexpr int val`? They both seem to do exactly the same.

Comment: which compiler do you use? `static_assert(PI1__ == 3, "");` is not allowed sinc `PI1__` is not a compile-time constant.

Comment: @HelloWorld I know that doesn't work. My question is why changing it to int makes it work. I'm using GCC 5.1 and VS 2015 Update 2.

Comment: Because by Standard `const int` is a compile time constant, but `const double` is not.

Comment: @SergeyA Where does the standard says that. That's the part where I'm confused. Why is const int a compile time constant and const double is not, it doesn't makes sense in my eyes.

Comment: @Phantom, answered in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments it seems like OP is asking for Standard quote which defines `const int` as a compile-time constant, but `const double` as not.

The corresponding details are found in 5.19, `Constant Expressions`. In particular:

> ...an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) unless it is applied to a
>   non-volatile glvalue of **integral or enumeration type** that refers to a
>   non-volatile const object with a preceding initialization, initialized
>   with a constant expression...

`int` is an integral type, while `double` is not.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your answer in the comment this is my answer. The C++ standard makes it pretty clear. GCC 5.1 works pretty fine here though: https://godbolt.org/g/2oV6Hk

> A converted constant expression of type T is an expression, implicitly converted to type T, where the converted
>   expression is a constant expression and the implicit conversion sequence contains only
>   § 5.20 134
>   c ISO/IEC N4567
>
> [...]
>
> **(4.6) — integral promotions (4.5),**
>
> **(4.7) — integral conversions (4.7) other than narrowing conversions (8.5.4)**,
>
> [...]

For the reference for narrowing conversions (8.5.4/7) in n4567:

> A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion
>
> - from a floating-point type to an integer type, or
> - from long double to double or float, or from double to float, except where the source is a constant expression and the actual value after conversion is within the range of values that can be represented (even if it cannot be represented exactly), or
> - from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to a ﬂoating-point type, except where the source is a constant expression and the actual value after conversion will fit into the target type and will produce the original value when converted back to the original type, or
> - from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all the values of the original type, except where the source is a constant expression and the actual value after conversion will fit into the target type and will produce the original value when converted back to the original type.

Comment: I meant `PI3__ = PI1__`, not `PI3__ = P1`. I've updated my question. The question I guess is why const int is a compile time constant, and const double is not a compile time constant.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler does not allow an implicit narrowing or non-integral promotion during the initialisation of a constexpr variable.

This will work:

```
int main()
{
    const int PI1 = 3;
    constexpr int PI2 = 3;
    constexpr int PI3 = PI1;  // works
    static_assert(PI1 == 3, "");  // works

    const double PI1__ = 3;
    constexpr double PI2__ = 3;
    constexpr double PI3__ = double(PI1);  // works with explicit cast
    static_assert(PI2__ == 3, "");  // works now. PI1__ isn't constexpr
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is the narrowing happening?

Comment: PI1 is an int. PI3__ is a double.

Comment: @SergeyA and actually, HelloWorld is right. It's a non-integral promotion. not narrowing..

Comment: @Phantom the code at the end of that link is not the same as mine. I took the code from what the OP posted. It's different to what his link points to.