# Vector of arrays of fixed size decided at runtime

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
int x=128, y=256;
std::vector<std::array<float,x*y>> codes;
```

Obviously this is wrong, while this is correct:

```
std::vector<std::array<float,128*256>> codes;
```

One solution to the first problem could be using macros like:

```
#define x 128
#define y 256
...
std::vector<std::array<float,x*y>> codes;
```

But I was wondering if there is another solution at run-time and not compile-time. **Notice** it's not necessary to use `std::array`, I need a `std::vector` of arrays (or whatever) of `x*y` elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `const`:

```
const int x = 128;
const int y = 256;
...
std::vector<std::array<float,x*y>> codes;
```

The problem in your first code was in the fact that `x` and `y` were not constants, so compiler could not rely on the fact that their values will not change in runtime and, consequently, was unable to determine the template argument value at compile-time.

Comment: Might I suggest `constexpr`? That way if you try to get `x` and `y` from runtime values, you'll get a compiler complaint at that point rather than when you instantiate `codes`.

Comment: Voilà, it worked! Thanks! Anyway, since `x` and `y` are decided at run-time by the user, can we declare them without initializing them and do it in a second moment (when the user insert the value, i.e. 128 and 256)?

Comment: @user975989 Agree that `constexpr` is probably better here. Have no new compiler on hand to check.

Comment: @justHelloWorld To create an array which size is unknown at compile-time, you cannot use `std::array`. Consider using `std::vector` instead. `std::vector` has a wonderful constructor which allows you to specify size and a value to fill: `vector<vector<float>> codes(size1, vector<float>(size2, 0))`.

Comment: @user975989 I'm sorry, can you try to explain again why `constexpr` should be better? First time that I see it!

Comment: @justHelloWorld Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36405541/constexpr-vs-const-vs-constexpr-const