# Why can't I declare a constexpr local, when a const one works?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

What the difference between `up` and `up1` here?

Why does `const` work, but not `constexpr`?

```
class vec3 {
    int x, y, z;
public:
    vec3(int x, int y, int z) : x{x}, y{y}, z{z} {}
};

int main()
{
    // Error C2127'up': illegal initialization of 'constexpr'
    // entity with a non-constant expression
    constexpr vec3 up{0, 1, 0};

    const vec3 up1{0, 1, 0};
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell from a poorly cropped image. What is `vec3`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [const vs constexpr on variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346879/const-vs-constexpr-on-variables)

Comment: Please provide [mcve], as text, with a copy-pasted **compiler** error message. What you are trying to show, is **not** an error message from a compiler.

Comment: Quoting g++: "'vec3' is not an aggregate, does not have a trivial default constructor, and has no constexpr constructor that is not a copy or move constructor"

Comment: Your class needs constexpr in front of the Dtor

Comment: @JVApen I think you mean Ctor.

Comment: You are right, should have been Ctor

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a `constexpr` object, then the corresponding constructor needs to be `constexpr` as well. So, the constructor needs to be like this:

```
constexpr vec3(int x, int y, int z) : x{x}, y{y}, z{z} {}
```

(If the initialization of a `constexpr` object involves calling a function, then the function needs to be constexpr as well. A constructor is not an exception to this rule.)