# How to get a public constant from an object?

Tags: c++, class, switch-statement, constants

When I do this

```
Txtbin a;

switch(err){
    case a.ERR_EMPTY_IMAGE:
        std::cerr << "Error: Image is empty\n" << std::endl;
        break;
}
```

I get this error

> txtbin.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’: txtbin.cpp:97:11:
>   error: the value of ‘a’ is not usable in a constant expression
>       case a.ERR_EMPTY_IMAGE:
>              ^

The constant `ERR_EMPTY_IMAGE` is defined as follows in the class:

```
public:
    const int ERR_EMPTY_IMAGE   = 2;
```

Comment: Make it `static`.

Comment: @user207421 how?

Comment: This may come as a shock, but add the keyword `static` to the declaration. Further changes are required, but I would expect any competent programmer to be able to make them, just like this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In short

In your class `Txtbin`, define the const as static:

```
public:
    static const int ERR_EMPTY_IMAGE   = 2;
```

then

```
switch(err){
    case Txtbin::ERR_EMPTY_IMAGE:
        std::cerr << "Error: Image is empty\n" << std::endl;
        break;
}
```

### In very long, with all the explanations

#### Why static ?

In fact the way you initialize your constant makes clear that it is not specific to any object: You do not intend to have a different value for `ERR_EMPTY_IMAGE` in two objects of your class.

The right way to tell this to the compiler is to make this const `static`. This makes the constant independent of any object of the class.  You can then refer to it only with `Txtbin::ERR_EMPTY_IMAGE` wherever you want.

Once it is static, you could also keep using `a.ERR_EMPTY_IMAGE` in the `switch`, since the compiler will find out that it doesn't need the non-const object `a` to determine the value.

Note also that the size of the objects would also be smaller since static values do not need to be duplicated in every instance.

#### Why is const not sufficient here ?

You can very well have a public `const` that is different for every object of the class:

```
class Test2 {
public:
    const  int ERR_EMPTY_IMAGE;    
    Test2(int x) : ERR_EMPTY_IMAGE{x} {}
};
 
Test2 c(5), d(6); 
cout << "Test2 c ->"<< c.ERR_EMPTY_IMAGE<<" d->"<< d.ERR_EMPTY_IMAGE<<endl;
```

The const does only tell that the value of the member does not change once the object is constructed. And this is why your compiler complained in the first instance: the const is not sufficient for the compiler to define it at compile time.   Proof:

```
class Test1 {
public:
    const  int ERR_EMPTY_IMAGE   = 2;  
    Test1() = default;                  // default constructor 
    Test1(int x) : ERR_EMPTY_IMAGE{x} {}
};

Test1 b;  
Test1 b_ouch(9); 
cout << "Sizeof b: "<< sizeof(b) <<endl;  
cout << "Test1 b ->"<< b.ERR_EMPTY_IMAGE<<" b_ouch->"<< b_ouch.ERR_EMPTY_IMAGE<<endl;
```

Here an [online demo](https://ideone.com/klF1vA) of what is said above

#### Would constexpr be even better ?

`constexpr` is the way to say to the compiler that you expect the expression to be constant at compile time. So the kind of expression you could use in a `case`.

Now for all the reasons explained above, `constexpr` requires anyway your member variable to be `static`:

```
public:
    constexpr static int ERR_EMPTY_IMAGE   = 2;
```

The main advantage of `constexpr` in your  case would be to highlight any misunderstandings sooner.  Because you could very well have your member defined like this

```
public:
    const static int ERR_EMPTY_IMAGE;
```

and initialize its value outside the class. This makes it very tricky.   Semantically, for C++ this is still a static constant (i.e. its value will never change).  And in the compilation unit in which the constant is initialized, it'll be used as a compile time constant thanks to constant propagation.  But in other compilation units, its value is not known at compile time (it might be known only at link time).

With `constexpr` instead of `const` the compiler would immediately complain by telling you that the initialization is missing in the declaration.  So it could be an advantage to use it,  at least if you do not have to use some older compiler.

Comment: Would `constexpr` be better practice? Assuming your compiler supports C++11

Comment: @Ayxan `constexpr static` then - see [here](https://ideone.com/x1anpP)

Comment: @Ayxan Would be better practice why?

Comment: @Ayxan: From C++17 on, yes, before that there are some really strange things with constexpr constants

Comment: @user207421 since constexpr is explicitly resolved at compile time

Comment: @Ayxan And so is `const'. Still waiting ...

Comment: @user207421 [`constexpr` shall be a compile time constant, `const` may or may not be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13347355/10147399). It doesn't make much difference for integers but for consistency, it might be considered a better practice. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @Ayxan I have edited the answer with additional explanations if OP wants to know more, and clarifying the potential benefit of constexpr.

Comment: @Ayxan Ah yes, and I just read your answer behind your link, which raises also the advantage related to constexpr propagation.