# constexpr int and constexpr double in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, integer, double, constexpr

I have encountered a strange case.

```
// this does not work, and reports:
// constexpr variable 'b' must be initialized by a constant expression
int main() {
  const double a = 1.0;
  constexpr double b = a;
  std::cout << b << std::endl;
}

// this works...
int main() {
  const int a = 1;
  constexpr int b = a;
  std::cout << b << std::endl;
}
```

anything special about `double` so it cannot make `constexpr` work?

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346879/const-vs-constexpr-on-variables).

Answer (score 6):

> anything special about `double` so it cannot make `constexpr` work?

`int`s and `double`s behave differently in this case.

For [core constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression#Core_constant_expressions), `a` in the 2nd case (with type `int`) is [usable in constant expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression#Usable_in_constant_expressions) , but `a` in the 1st case (with type `double`) isn't.

> A core constant expression is any expression whose evaluation would
>   not evaluate any one of the following:
>
> - 9. an lvalue-to-rvalue implicit conversion unless....
>
>      - a. applied to a non-volatile glvalue that designates an object that is usable in constant expressions (see below),
>
>        ```
>        int main() {
>            const std::size_t tabsize = 50;
>            int tab[tabsize]; // OK: tabsize is a constant expression
>                              // because tabsize is usable in constant expressions
>                              // because it has const-qualified integral type, and
>                              // its initializer is a constant initializer
>
>            std::size_t n = 50;
>            const std::size_t sz = n;
>            int tab2[sz]; // error: sz is not a constant expression
>                          // because sz is not usable in constant expressions
>                          // because its initializer was not a constant initializer
>        }
>        ```

and

(emphasis mine)

> Usable in constant expressions In the list above, a variable is usable
>   in constant expressions if it is
>
> - a constexpr variable, or
> - it is a constant-initialized variable
>
>   - of reference type or
>   - of **const-qualified integral** or enumeration type.

You can declare `a` as `constexpr` to make it usable in constant expression. e.g.

```
constexpr double a = 1.0;
constexpr double b = a;   // works fine now
```