# Initializing a two dimensional array with class static const integers

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, constants

I'm declaring a three-dimensional array as a class member, using static const class members as the first two bounds:

```
class A
{
    static const uint8_t screenWidth = 256;
    static const uint8_t screenHeight = 240;

    uint8_t buffer[screenHeight][screenWidth ][3];
}
```

in Visual Studio 2019 I get the following (weird?) error:

```
Error (active)  E0098   an array may not have elements of this type
```

if I resort to the "enum hack" in order to declare class-local compile time integer constants it works:

```
class A
{
    enum { SH = 240, SW = 256};
    uint8_t buffer[SH][SW][3];
}
```

shouldn't the former example be C++11 compliant code? (I guess Visual Studio 2019 compiler is).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13346879/1216776

Comment: @stark `const` and `constexpr` have the same effect in this case. Integral types have special rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that, in the declaration:

```cpp
static const uint8_t screenWidth = 256;
```

the value `256` is not valid for a `uint8_t` type (range is 0 thru 255), and it 'rolls over' to give an *actual* value of **zero** - which is invalid for an array dimension.

Make your dimension 'constants' bigger types, and your code will work:

```cpp
class A {
    static const uint16_t screenWidth = 256;
    static const uint16_t screenHeight = 240;

    uint8_t buffer[screenHeight][screenWidth][3];
};
```

Comment: ok, my bad, but why doesn't it work anyway? shouldn't it truncate the value and use that as constant? the compiler error message is obscure to say the least

Comment: it's a zero, that's why

Comment: It does 'truncate' - but to zero! (You will get the same error message if you declare either of the literals as `0`.)

Answer (score 4):

I think that an object of the type `uint8_t` is unable to contain the value 256.:)

Why not just to use the type `size_t` instead of the type `uint8_t`?

```
static const size_t screenWidth = 256;
static const size_t screenHeight = 240;
```

Comment: @Luca  In general it is a bad idea. From the C++ Standard "If the initializer-clause is an expression
and a narrowing conversion (8.5.4) is required to convert the expression, the program is ill-formed" In your case the value is truncated to 0.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is with `uint8_t`

```
static const uint8_t screenWidth = 256;//effectively 0
```

overflows and is exactly a big round ZERO. See [integer-overflow](/questions/tagged/integer-overflow).

To fix, switch to eg. `size_t` (also more appropriate for sizes)

Comment: you link integer-overflow but this is unsigned integer overflow, one is (still) UB the other not

Comment: @idclev463035818 that tag is for both i believe.

Comment: yes, but here the distinction matters. Not a big deal, just thought it is worth mentioning

Comment: @idclev463035818 It is only UB in arithmetic operations. Conversion from integral type to signed integral type is modulo 2^N in C++20 and was *implementation-defined* before. Calling it "*overflow*" at all is probably inaccurate.

Comment: @walnut thanks for clarification. Learned something today: check ;)