# What am I missing in defining an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have been trying to learn arrays and I can't seem to define an array.

```
const int size = 10;
??[size];
```

Can anybody spot my mistakes? Thank You.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: `const` does not make something a constant -- you need `constexpr`

Comment: @ChrisDodd No, `const int` is enough. `const` integral types initialized by constant expressions are specifically exempt from the `constexpr` requirement.

Comment: *I have been trying to learn arrays and I can't seem to define an array.* -- That's surprising, since every C++ language book that's out there shows how to declare an array.  Where are you learning C++?

Comment: @emmali padron The question does not make a sense.

Comment: Wait while I *consult my C++ reference book section on arrays ..."

Answer (score 2):

To declare an array using a constant, you should use this syntax:

```
// constexpr is explicitly compile time constant
constexpr int size = 10;
int my_array[size]; // int array, can be changed to float
```

For dynamic array, use vector:

```
int size = ...;
std::vector<int> my_array;
array.resize(size);
```

You can also use modern statically sized array:

```
constexpr int size = 10;
std::array<int, size> my_array;
```

Comment: Why not `std::vector<int> array(size);`?  Also, the `constexpr` is not required.  For integer types, just `const` works.

Comment: @NathanOliver I avoid confusion with initializer list. When a class has overloaded constructors with initializer list that could be in conflict, I simply not use those constructors in answers, especially to beginners. Also, the parens `()` are too close to `[]`, which a very beginner could confuse.

Comment: @NathanOliver Of course, if `[size]` could be placed on the type, and constructors would never change when you change syntax between `{}` and `()`, and vexing parse woudn't be a problem, I would simply use the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
const int size = 10;
type array[size];
```

Is what you want. Substitute `type` for any type (i.e. `int`, `float`, `bool` etc.).

In this case, specifying array size using a `const` variable is valid, but there are many cases where it isn't. You'd probably want to learn the [difference between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346879/const-vs-constexpr-on-variables) `const` and `constexpr`.

Also, instead of learning by asking questions here, try finding a good c++ source: a book, online article series or a video tutorial. It'll definitely accelerate your education.