# How to push a large git repository without launching a git pack-index command?

Tags: git, ssh, 32-bit, git-push, git-fsck

I know about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12855926/how-to-handle-a-large-git-repository). I already performed my local modifications, however it seem, the official git project perform a`git fsck`locally before pushing to origin.

```
C:\Cygwin\home\example\utils>git push origin master
Warning: Permanently added '196.30.252.130' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 2285522160 bytes)
```

and the command fails…

The problem is while the pack format allows it *(size_t or unsigned long)*, the official git project use 32 bits signed integers internally for handling tree objects size *(limiting to 2Gb)*.

***So is there a command that won’t perform an fsck before pushing ? Or an another project/library (I couldn't found how to do it with libgit2) allowing me to stay on my laptop ?***
An alternative would be to get documentation about the git over ssh protocol, so I can implement that part myself.

Comment: The project isn’t on github, so using lfs isn’t an option.

Comment: `git push` over ssh just invokes `git receive-pack` in an ssh session on the remote machine, and creates a bidirectional pipe between it and the local `git send-pack`. The only protocol is that between `send-pack` and `receive-pack`.

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols

Comment: @hobbs : I took a debugger, and it invoke functions of fsck.c. Checking this is as easy as setting a breakpoint that catch the execution of a line in that file.

Comment: @hobbs : Ok the pack problem is more difficult to solve than fsck.