# GIT (DVCS) - Lock or checked out the file (as like svn) and conflict merge the files

Tags: git, git-svn

I am just moving from SVN to GIT.  I have gone through the posts and comments but not finding effective solution.

I have a below questions:

1. How to checked out or Lock the files so, other developer is aware that file is unavailable and checked out by 
   this user ?
2. If one user has updated the same file where other user is working on and both have push the changes to master repository. Now, how it resolve the conflicts or merge.
   How conflict or merge works.
   Do we have a option to manage conflicts in tortoiseGIT or internally manage by GIT repositories push command. ?

Please let me know the above questions resolution.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git is a distributed vcs so anything you do will be done to your local repository which itself is unaware of the local repositories of the other developers. So to answer question 1:
Since git doesn't have a central server repository (you can make one but it's only a central repository by your definition not by the design of git) there is no instance that can lock files like in svn.

There is a detailed article [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows) on team workflows.

Merge conflicts are managed by git as far as possible. If it can't resolve it will show that a merge conflict exists for manual resolve.

Comment: To answer your 2nd question: [merging-with-git](https://github.com/bricoleurs/bricolage/wiki/Merging-with-Git) 
Basically when you try to perform a push of your commit, git will notify you that your file needs to be merged/edited in order to be able to push it. Merging can be done using git or any other tool (it's just a matter of editing the conflictual lines).

Comment: As an additional remark: Pushing to a shared branch on shared repository is usually not the best option and can turn bad pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding 2., rebase first your local commits on top of the fetched remote branch (the one the other dev has already push).
The rebase will trigger merges if needed.
You resolve them locally, *then* push your commits.