# What is version control software in .net

Tags: asp.net, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Source Control for a .Net guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694596/source-control-for-a-net-guy)

Can any one help me to know what is version control software in .net and give me any good tutorials for start up users.

Thanks,
@nag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a newbie, try using Visual Studio Express from the very beginning, it will pay off later.

TFS 11 Express is free for up to 5 users and it is easy to use

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads#express

And this small PDF file will explain in simple terms how to use it:

http://sstjean.blogspot.com/2006/10/document-from-vss-to-tfs-introduction.html

Comment: Exactly. He needs software for source control and this one is one of the easiest